# how to ignore a directory in meld?

Tags: meld

I am doing a directory comparison using Meld v3.20.4 on Ubuntu 20.04

I want to ignore a directory that looks like this

```
a
└── b
    ├── c
    │   ├── c1.csv
    │   ├── c2.log
    │   └── c3.txt
    └── d
        ├── d1.csv
        └── d1.txt
```

I want to ignore anything under directory `b`.  I have tried adding a file filter like `a/b/*`.  Doesn't work.  Any help?

Answer (score 0):

You can add the "b" folder in a new entry to the File Filters in Meld Preferences, but that will exclude all files and folders with the same name...